# Unable to update the item in DynamoDB using the GSI

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have the following structure in my dynamodb table:-
id: partition_key
user_id: GSI

Following is my Lambda where I'm trying to get the value of **user_id** from the client in the user object (in JSON) and then trying to update the **Dynamodb** item using the query operation but it is not working:-

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
  logger.info('event:', event);
  let body, data;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'
  };
  const user = JSON.parse(event.body).user;
  const updatedOn = new Date().getTime();
  try {
    const params = {
      TableName: ddbTable,
      IndexName: 'user_id-index',
      KeyConditionExpression: 'user_id = :id',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':id': user.id
      }
    };

    dynamodb.query(params, function (err, result) {
      console.log("result", result);
      data = result;
      if (err) {
        console.log("Unable to query item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err));
      } else {
        const parameters = {
          TableName: ddbTable,
          Key: {
            "id": result.Items[0].id
          },
          UpdateExpression: "set first_name = :f, last_name = :l, postal_code = :p, country_code = :c, updated_on = :u",
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":f": user.firstName,
            ":l": user.lastName,
            ":p": user.postalCode,
            ":c": user.countryCode,
            ":u": updatedOn
          },
          ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
        };
        dynamodb.update(parameters, function (err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          else console.log(data);
        });
      }
    });
    console.log("*********");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
    return err;
  } finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(data);
  }
  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers
  };
};
```

The query operation is not working at all.
This statement is not getting executed

```
dynamodb.query(params, function (err, result) {
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What's not working?  What error messages are you receiving?  What's in the CloudWatch logs?

Comment: @fedonev, it is simply printing these logs console.log("params", params); and console.log("*********"); on the CloudWatch. Lambda is unable to Query DynamoDB i.e. this statement is not executing dynamodb.query(params, function (err, result) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [two patterns to invoke asynchronous calls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html) such as `dynamodb.query` in a Node.js Lambda handlers: async-await or callbacks.  Because your handler implements neither correctly, the Lambda returns without the SDK calls finishing.

The recommended approach is async-await.  Add the `await` keyword and promisify the method with `.promise()`.  This pattern is preferred because it removes the "callback hell" of nested SDK calls.

```js
const queryResult = await dynamodb.query(params).promise()

const updateParams = {
  Key: { "id": queryResult.Items[0].id },
  ...
}

const updateResult = await dynamodb.update(updateParams).promise()
```

For callback pattern examples, see the above link or [this](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/lambda_functions/apigateway/apigateway-microservice.js) from the awsdocs repo.

Note: [AWS SDK for JavaScript v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/migrating-to-v3.html) is now stable and the recommended version.